# Find a point 90° left or right from a point (x,y,z) in a 3D space.

Tags: geometry, vector-spaces, 3d

How can I find a point which is 90° left or right from a point (x,y,z) in a 3D space?

for example if I have the point $(x,y,z)$ how to find $(x1,y1,z1)$ and $(x2,y2,z2)$.
[image]

Comment: Which angles are $90^o$?

Comment: considering z values as 0 maybe! like 90° left or right from a point.

Comment: @JAVY So if you don't know what the question means, where did it come from?

Comment: I don't know how to express it, it is my question & is related to my small work , **I am creating a 3d web view, so from a point I want to find a point that is 90° left from my view point(which I have).**@almagest

Comment: I think my question is unclear , I'm sorry , I'll better study my problem again and come here later if I need, with more specific details.

Answer (score 1):

Consider an arbitrary point $(x_1,y_1,z_1)$ and the vector $v=(x-x_1,y-y_1,z-z_1)$

In $\Bbb{R^3}$ there are infinitely many vectors $u=(x',y',z')$ satisfying $u\cdot v=0$

To find one of these, and thus a point with the desired property, we have $u\cdot v=0\Rightarrow x'(x-x_1)+y'(y-y_1)+z'(z-z_1)=0$.

So if for example you have $2x'-3y'+6z'=0$, then one such point would be $(2,1,\frac16)$ and another $(3,0,1)$.

PS Left or Right is meaningless in $\Bbb{R^3}$.

Answer (score 1):

There is no right or left in a three dimensional world. With reference to the present direction of motion you have three degrees of freedom, pitch, roll or yaw. You need to roll right or left by $90^0.$

You can apply *Euler angles:* $ \theta ,\phi, \psi$ to a rigid body by means of a matrix multiplication populated mostly with $(1,-1,0) $. References and details are available on net.